# Simple hidden field in non-model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What's the simplest way in Ruby-on-Rails to create several simple hidden fields with known values and the same name in a number of non-model forms (form_remote_tag in my case, but I'm guessing that isn't relevant)?

By "simple hidden field", I mean one where the name is just a single string (`field_name`) rather than part of an array (`field_name[]`), so that the value can be read simply from the params hash as `params[:field_name]` rather than `params[:field_name][0]`.

I have found that

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => {:action => "do_act"} do %>
  <%= hidden_field :field_name, 0, :name => "field_name", :value => "foo" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

produces an acceptable element (`<input id="field_name_0" name="field_name" type="hidden" value="foo" />`), but if I omit the `:name` parameter then the rendered field has the name `field_name[0]`. Omitting the `0` obviously causes really odd behaviour.

`<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, "foo" %>` produces an acceptable element if there's only one such form, but generates HTML warnings (duplicate IDs) if there are more than one.

Is there a way to do this (barring defining a helper) in fewer arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `hidden_field_tag` and set the ID manually based on some value that is different for each form. Like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, 'value', :id => 'field_name_' + unique_value %>
```

Where `unique_value` can be anything at all. If these forms have some sort of parent record that they refer to, it could be the ID of the parent. I assume that's why you have multiple similar forms on the same page in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple pass the ID as an option. The method (form_tag_helper.rb) is defined as:

```
def hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
  text_field_tag(name, value, options.stringify_keys.update("type" => "hidden"))
end
```

So writing:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, "foo", :id => "hidden_field_1" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, "bar", :id => "hidden_field_2" %>
```

Produces:

```
<input id="hidden_field_1" name="field_name" type="hidden" value="foo" />
<input id="hidden_field_2" name="field_name" type="hidden" value="bar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, "foo" %>
```

Comment: Ah, that works - but makes me realise I've understated my question. I actually have a number of forms, all of which submit to the same action with different values in the hidden field - so this generates warnings because the input ids are the same.